# C# - Use Reflection to Extract List of Values from a List<Class>

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, collections

I have a List which contains a class and would like to be able to use reflection to iterate through each property in that class and generate a List containing each property's values.  I have no problem using reflection to get all of the properties, but where I’m failing is in the syntax to iteratively extract a list of each property’s value.

Example Code:

```
public class ExampleClass
{
    public double Val1 {get; set;}
    public double Val2 { get; set; }
    public double Val3 { get; set; }

    public ExampleClass(double val1, double val2, double val3)
    {
        this.Val1 = val1;
        this.Val2 = val2;
        this.Val3 = val3 ;
    }
}

public class Main
{
    public Main()
    {
        List<ExampleClass> exampleList = new List<ExampleClass>();

        exampleList.Add(new ExampleClass(1.1, 1.2, 1.3));
        exampleList.Add(new ExampleClass(2.1, 2.2, 2.3));
        exampleList.Add(new ExampleClass(3.1, 3.2, 3.3));


        List<PropertyInfo> properties = exampleList[0]
            .GetType()
            .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly)
            .ToList();

        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in properties)
        {
            // Extract each property into a list, e.g.
            // 1st pass: list containing 1.1, 2.1, and 3.1
            // 2nd pass: list containing 1.2, 2.2 and 3.2
            // 3rd pass: list containing 1.3, 2.3 and 3.3
        }
    }
}
```

If I was to manually specify the property I wanted I could use something like this:

```
var test = exampleList.Select(X => X.Val1).ToList();
```

Unfortunately, my best guesses look like the following and generate a “Object reference not set to an instance of an object” error

```
var test1 = collectionCompletionList.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name).GetValue(collectionCompletionList, null);
```

What (presumably) simple thing am I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You almost got it. The `GetValue` method of the `PropertyInfo` class takes object whose property value will be returned as the argument. So you need to pass it items of your list and not the list itself.

```
foreach (PropertyInfo prop in properties) {
    var propertiesValues = exampleList.Select(o => prop.GetValue(o)).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate the collection and the properties.

```
Dictionary<string, ArrayList> allIterationValues = new Dictionary<string, ArrayList>();

foreach (PropertyInfo prop in properties)
{
    ArrayList iterationList = new ArrayList();
    allIterationValues.Add(prop.Name, iterationList);

    foreach (var element in exampleList)
    {
        iterationList.Add(prop.GetValue(element, null));
    }
}
// Check the value of allIterationValues here
```